# how do I correct text sizes on the web?

Tags: firefox, fonts, text

I open for instance http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2013/07/warrantless-cell-tracking/ and the text on the left hand (story) is very small, but the test on the right (advertisements) is quite readable.
Is there a way to fix this? By the way, this ask ubuntu page loads fine.

Comment: I think this is a matter of the text font and theme the owner of the site uses. Is not a matter of yours (or Ubuntu OS). You can grow the size on a browser with CTRL and + buttons (decrease with CTRL and -), but the advertisements will grow as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what browser you are using, but if Firefox, have you tried something like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) ? That might be a good place to start. You can control the way web pages display utilising that add-on.If you go the user scripts, might find one that can work for you as well.

HTH

Comment: I am afraid that Nikth is correct. It is a pain to enlarge and shrink fonts all the time. AND I am trying Greasemonkey. Had never heard of that before. Thanks for the help.